# JGraph(T) graph element selection customization

Tags: java, jgrapht

I have as some problem with using JGraph(T) library.
I need change default selection view, example: default background is orange color, if vertex selected then green border was added, can i change this visualization strategy to change background to Color.BLUE on selected element.
I try execute follow code:

```
 GraphSelectionModel graphSelectionModel = new DefaultGraphSelectionModel(jGraph);
    graphSelectionModel.setSelectionMode(GraphSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_GRAPH_SELECTION);
    graphSelectionModel.addGraphSelectionListener(new GraphSelectionListener()
    {
        HashMap oldestCellsAndAttrs = new HashMap();
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(GraphSelectionEvent e)
        {
            jGraph.getModel().beginUpdate();
            m_jgAdapter.edit(oldestCellsAndAttrs, null, null, null);
            oldestCellsAndAttrs.clear();
            Map cellAndAttrs = new HashMap();
            for (Object obj : e.getCells())
            {
                DefaultGraphCell cell = (DefaultGraphCell) obj;
                oldestCellsAndAttrs.put(cell, JGraphModelAdapter.createDefaultVertexAttributes());
                Map attrs = cell.getAttributes();
                GraphConstants.setBackground(attrs, Color.BLUE);
                cellAndAttrs.put(cell, attrs);
            }
            m_jgAdapter.edit(cellAndAttrs, null, null, null);
            jGraph.getModel().endUpdate();
        }
    });
    fillGraph(tree, g);
    layout(g, m_jgAdapter, jGraph);
    setSize(3 * width / 4, height);
    jGraph.setSelectionModel(graphSelectionModel);
```

This change bkg on same selected objs, but not return after non-selection.
Is exists default solve for this problem ?

Answer (score 3):

I solve problem with foollowing code:

```
            @Override
        public void valueChanged(GraphSelectionEvent e)
        {
           Object[] cells = e.getCells();
            HashMap<DefaultGraphCell, AttributeMap> cellsAndAttrs = new HashMap<DefaultGraphCell, AttributeMap>();
            for (Object c : cells)
            {
                DefaultGraphCell cell = (DefaultGraphCell) c;
                AttributeMap cellAttrs = cell.getAttributes();
                if (jGraph.isCellSelected(cell))
                    GraphConstants.setBackground(cellAttrs, SELECTED_COLOR);
                else
                    GraphConstants.setBackground(cellAttrs, NON_SELECTED_COLOR);
                cellsAndAttrs.put(cell, cellAttrs);
            }
            m_jgAdapter.edit(cellsAndAttrs, null, null, null);
        }
```